# Angular Subscribe valuechanges in formarray in form group

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I'm  angular8 and I have a form array inside of form group but I want to detect new changes of a certain input.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.makeForm = this.fb.group({

     
      
      year:['', Validators.required],
      amount:['', Validators.required],
      desc:['', Validators.required],
      details: new FormArray([
        this.det(), 
      ])
    })


det(){
      return new FormGroup({
        requestfor     : new FormControl(''),
        remarks        : new FormControl('')
    })}
```

I have to check the data that every value changes in formarray values. But I am getting error if I use

```
this.makeForm.value.details.get('requestfor').valueChanges
```

and the error is

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of undefined
```

how to get the value inside of form array value

How to get the value.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need subscribe to valuesChanges, when you create the FormGroup

```
det(){
   //use an auxiliar const
   const group=new FormGroup({
        requestfor     : new FormControl(''),
        remarks        : new FormControl(''),
        // file_id        : new FormControl(''),
    })}
    //subscribe
    group.get('requestForm').valueChanges.subscribe(res=>{
    })
    //return group
    return group;
}
```

<strike>You can also has an array of Observables, and pass the index to your function det</strike>

```
changesArray:Observable[]=[] //<--don't forget initialize

det(index=0){
   //use an auxiliar const
   const group=new FormGroup({
        requestfor     : new FormControl(''),
        remarks        : new FormControl(''),
        // file_id        : new FormControl(''),
    })}
    //fill the array
    this.changesArray[index]=group.get('requestForm').valueChanges
    //return group
    return group;
}
```

<strike>And when you add or delete a new group to the formArray subscribe to a forkJoin of the array</strike>

```
 if (this.subscriptions)
    this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();

 this.subscriptions=forkJoin(changesArray)
    this.subscriptions.subscribe(res=>{
 })
```

**Update**
If we want control the whole array, we can define an array of observables and a subcriptions:

```
  observables:Observable<any>[]=[]
  suscription:Subscription
```

We need make a function where we are going to subscribe to a CombineLastest

```
  controlChange()
  {
    if (this.suscription)
      this.suscription.unsubscribe()

    this.suscription=combineLatest(this.observables.map(
      (o,i)=>o.pipe(startWith(this.array.controls.length>i?this.array.value[i].one:null))
      )).subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res)
    })

  }
```

We call to this function, when remove an element

```
  removeGroup(index)
  {
    this.array.removeAt(index);
    this.observables.splice(index,1)
    this.controlChange()
  }
```

And in function group Array add a new element to this.observables

```
  groupArray(data:any=null)
  {
    data=data || {one:null,two:null}
    const group=new FormGroup({
      one:new FormControl(data.one),
      two:new FormControl(data.two)
    })
    this.observables[this.array.controls.length]=group.get('one').valueChanges
    this.controlChange()
    return group
  }
```

NOTE: I this last part of code I use a getter

```
  get array() {
    return this.form.get("array") as FormArray;
  }
```

The [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8chimq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I'm happy about it, the second one it's WRONG, in a time I'll update the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.makeForm = this.fb.group({
    
         
          
          year:['', Validators.required],
          amount:['', Validators.required],
          desc:['', Validators.required],
          details: new FormArray([
            this.det(), 
          ])
        })
    
    
    det(){
          fomrgroup2 = new FormGroup({
            requestfor     : new FormControl(''),
            remarks        : new FormControl(''),
            // file_id        : new FormControl(''),
             })
          formgroup2.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
             console.log(val.requestfor);
             console.log(val.remarks);
             //One of those 2 here will be changed. Check their values and do whatever 
            //processing you want to do inside this subscription
               });
       return formgroup2;
    }
```